# Compare two arrays in Apps Script not working

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I´m a newbie to apps script, I want to do a price comparison script, I got two columns one column gets data via `blockspring addon` and `import.io`, this provide info about a website, one column name of the product and the other the price of this product. I want some way to notice me when price change, so I create a script that copy the values of this two columns , store them , and when i trigger it , it get the data from both columns and compare it , now for the test I have a simple alter box  that tells me if some data changes.

For now , I was able to wrote a script that get the values and compare it , but for some unknown reason it does not work.

This is my script. Maybe in the future I would like to alert what data in particular changes, but this is my first script son I try to take it easy.

This is the spreadsheet I´m working with

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HleYu-dCbUReOH-7SnEFipJa6E9wEcEzasQ7ns2tXso/edit?usp=sharing

```
function moveValuesOnly() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source1 = ss.getRange("A15:A105");
  var source2 = ss.getRange("B15:B105");
  var source3 = ss.getRange("A16:A105").getValues();
  var source4 = ss.getRange("E16:E105").getValues();
  var source5 = ss.getRange("E15:E105");

  if (source5.isBlank()) {

  source1.copyTo(ss.getRange("E15:E105"), {contentsOnly: true});
  source2.copyTo(ss.getRange("F15:F105"), {contentsOnly: true});
  Browser.msgBox('VALUES COPIED !', Browser.Buttons.OK);
}


if (source3 == source4) {
 Browser.msgBox('NOTHING CHANGES !', Browser.Buttons.OK);
}

 else {
 Browser.msgBox('SOMETHING CHANGES!', Browser.Buttons.OK);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to compare arrays by == method. You need to traverse through each and every element and do a comparison.

```
var Inspector = false;
for(var i=0;i<source3.length;i++)
{
 if(source3[i][0].toString() !=  source4[i][0].toString())
 {
 Inspector = true;
 }
}

if(Inspector)
{
 Browser.msgBox('SOMETHING CHANGES!', Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
else
{
Browser.msgBox('NOTHING CHANGES !', Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare ranges like that because they are 2-dimensional arrays. I modified your code and included a function to compare 2 columns. It won't work for ranges with more columns but it's easy to enhance it if you need it.

```
function moveValuesOnly() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source1 = ss.getRange("A15:A105");
  var source2 = ss.getRange("B15:B105");
  var source3 = ss.getRange("A16:A105").getValues();
  var source4 = ss.getRange("E16:E105").getValues();
  var source5 = ss.getRange("E15:E105");

  if (source5.isBlank()) {

    source1.copyTo(ss.getRange("E15:E105"), {contentsOnly: true});
    source2.copyTo(ss.getRange("F15:F105"), {contentsOnly: true});
    Browser.msgBox('VALUES COPIED !', Browser.Buttons.OK);
    }

  function equalColumns(col1, col2) {

    if (col1.length !== col2.length) return false;
    var equal = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < col1.length; i ++) {    
      if (col1[i][0] !== col2[i][0])  {        
        equal = false;
        break;
      }
    };    
    return equal;
  }


if (equalColumns(source3,source4)) {

    Browser.msgBox('NOTHING CHANGES !', Browser.Buttons.OK);
    }

  else {
    Browser.msgBox('SOMETHING CHANGES!', Browser.Buttons.OK);
    }

}
```